# Excel VBA search a word in a crossword of characters

Tags: excel, vba

I have a collection of characters in excel. I want to search a word in the collection. for example, I get the word "WATER" from input box and then I want to search "WATER" in the below range in six ways and then give a color index to the characters:

```
>horizontal left to right
>horizontal right to left
>vertical top to bottom
>vertical bottom to top
>diagonal top to bottom
>diagonal bottom to top

    A  B  C  D  E  F 
1   r  a  h  k  c  f 
2   h  u  m  n  d  e
3   w  a  t  e  r  r
4   k  t  y  e  s  q
5   p  y  x  q  e  r
```

I searched but couldn't find anything. It is beyond my skills and I wonder if anyone have a code about this problem?

Comment: I think you need to generate strings of each row, column and diagonal way. Then you can search with `InStr()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do it. Definitely not the most efficient, because there is a lot of moving to Excel and back, but works really well.

```
Sub Cross_words_out()

Dim strSearch As String
    strSearch = "water" ' <<<< your search word

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Dim rngA As Range
'Make sure your character collection is your CurrentRegion
Set rngA = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion 
Dim lRows As Long
    lRows = rngA.Rows.Count
Dim lCols As Long
    lCols = rngA.Columns.Count
Dim str As String
Dim lEval As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long 'counters

    'Horizontal forward
    For i = 1 To lRows
        str = vbNullString
        For j = 1 To lCols
            str = str & ws.Cells(i, j).Value2
        Next
        lEval = InStr(1, str, strSearch)
        If lEval > 0 Then
            For k = lEval To lEval + Len(strSearch) - 1
                ws.Cells(i, k).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
            Next
        End If
    Next

    'Horizontal backward
    For i = 1 To lRows
        str = vbNullString
        For j = lCols To 1 Step -1
            str = str & Cells(i, j).Value2
        Next
        lEval = InStr(1, str, strSearch)
        If lEval > 0 Then
            For k = lCols - lEval + 1 To _
                    lCols - lEval - Len(strSearch) + 2 Step -1
                ws.Cells(i, k).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
            Next
        End If
    Next

    'Vertical downward
    For i = 1 To lCols
        str = vbNullString
        For j = 1 To lRows
            str = str & Cells(j, i).Value2
        Next
        lEval = InStr(1, str, strSearch)
        If lEval > 0 Then
            For k = lEval To lEval + Len(strSearch) - 1
                ws.Cells(k, i).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
            Next
        End If
    Next

    'Vertical upward
    For i = 1 To lCols
        str = vbNullString
        For j = lRows To 1 Step -1
            str = str & Cells(j, i).Value2
        Next
        lEval = InStr(1, str, strSearch)
        If lEval > 0 Then
            For k = lRows - lEval + 1 To _
                    lRows - lEval - Len(strSearch) + 2 Step -1
                ws.Cells(k, i).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
            Next
        End If
    Next

    'Diagonal top to bottom, forward
    For i = lRows To 1 Step -1
        str = vbNullString
        j = 1
        Do
            str = str & ws.Cells(i + j - 1, j).Value2
            j = j + 1
        Loop While Not ws.Cells(i + j - 1, j).Value2 = Empty
        lEval = InStr(1, str, strSearch)
        If lEval > 0 Then
            For k = 1 To Len(strSearch)
                ws.Cells(i + lEval + k - 2, lEval + k - 1) _
                    .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
            Next
        End If
    Next
    For i = 2 To lCols
        str = vbNullString
        j = 0
        Do
            str = str & ws.Cells(1 + j, i + j).Value2
            j = j + 1
        Loop While Not ws.Cells(j, i + j).Value2 = Empty
        lEval = InStr(1, str, strSearch)
        If lEval > 0 Then
            For k = 1 To Len(strSearch)
                ws.Cells(lEval + k - 1, i + lEval + k - 2) _
                    .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
            Next
        End If
    Next

    'Diagonal bottom to top, forward
    For i = lRows To 1 Step -1
        str = vbNullString
        j = i
        Do
            str = str & ws.Cells(j, 1 + i - j).Value2
            j = j - 1
        Loop While Not j < 1 And _
            Not ws.Cells(i, 1 + i - j).Value2 = Empty
        lEval = InStr(1, str, strSearch)
        If lEval > 0 Then
            For k = 1 To Len(strSearch)
                ws.Cells(i - lEval - k + 2, lEval + k - 1) _
                    .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
            Next
        End If
    Next
    For i = 2 To lCols
        str = vbNullString
        j = 0
        Do
            str = str & ws.Cells(lRows - j, i + j).Value2
            j = j + 1
        Loop While Not j < 1 And _
            Not ws.Cells(lRows, i + j).Value2 = Empty
        lEval = InStr(1, str, strSearch)
        If lEval > 0 Then
            For k = 1 To Len(strSearch)
                ws.Cells(lRows - lEval - k + 2, i + lEval + k - 2) _
                    .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
            Next
        End If
    Next

Set rngA = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much. There is only a problem in diagonal bottom to top, forward, it can't find the characters in some places, for example if the first character of the "water"  be in the last row.

Answer (score 0):

The arrangements you have listed make the following number of strings:

1. 5 + 5 strings horizontally (forward and backward)
2. 6 + 6 strings vertically (downward and upward)
3. 4 + 4 strings diagonally (top to bottom and bottom to top)

so just create simple loops for each of the 3 cases and join all characters in the sequences to make-up strings. After that, all you need to do is to search for the word you're looking for using SubString function (`INSTR` in VBA).

An example of the loop would be (for forward-horizontal strings):

```
Dim S(4) as string
For i = 1 To 5
    S(i) = ""
    For j = 1 To 5
        S(i) = S(i) & Cells(i, j)
    Next        
Next
```

Comment: You might have many more diagonal strings if the string length can vary.